# What is the time complexity of my algorithm using a for loop?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have trouble with that exercise, how can I write it in Python, and get time complexity? Should use a `while` loop?

> Write an algorithm that returns the smallest value in the array `A[1 . . . n]`. Use a `while` loop. What is the time complexity of your algorithm?

```py
list1 = []
num = int(input("Enter number of elements in list: "))
 
for i in range(1, num + 1):
    ele = int(input("Enter elements: "))
    list1.append(ele)
     
print("Smallest element is:", min(list1))
```

Comment: The time complexity of this algorithm is O(n), since the while loop will run once for each element in the array.

Comment: 1) The exercise is asking you to write your own `min` function, don't use the built in one or you won't learn. 2) If you started reading the wiki on [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities)  before creating an account on this website you would have already known the answer.

Comment: @HoxhaAlban, there is no need to be rude. Just point him the right direction and that is it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

#### How to get the time complexity?

Most of the time when someone is asking you for time complexity they aren't asking for exact time complexity, they are asking for an approximate estimate in terms of [Big O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).  I highly recommend you check out this wiki but in short, Big O Notation asks "For 'n' elements how many steps will your algorithm take in the worst case?"

So if we look at your algorithm, we can see that there is a list of 'n' elements.  Now in the worst case the smallest element is the last element of the list so in this case your algorithm would have to search through all 'n' elements to find the lowest number.  In this case your Big O would be O(n) or [linear time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time).  As 'n' grows your algorithm time will take a linearly increasing amount of time to execute.

#### Should I use `while` loop?

Technically speaking it doesn't matter too much, but it sounds like they may be asking you to use a while loop so you can get more experience using `while` loops.